# Send form data in a querystring to url with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am trying to create a simple for that then passes the data into a querystring.

ie capturing:
first name
last name
email

Which when submitted with give soemthing like:

http://www.url.com?FirstName=John&LastName=Smith&johnsmith@url.com

I thought I would try 2 way binding and add the querystrings via the action but obviously this gave me an error. I don't need to save this data trust transfer it from a small form to the main application.

I also tried doing this all on submit which works however the link is still clickable when the form is blank. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

```
<form class="form" name="appForm" novalidate action="https://www.url.com?FirstName={{firstname}}" method="Post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-11 flowuplabels">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback" show-errors="{ showSuccess: true }">
            <div class="fl_wrap">
              <label for="appfirstname" class="fieldLabel fl_label">
                First name<span class="text-danger">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" name="appfirstname" id="appfirstname" class="form-control fl_input" data-ng-model="firstname" ng-required />
              <span class="form-bar"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback" show-errors="{ showSuccess: true }">
            <div class="fl_wrap">
              <label for="applastname" class="fieldLabel fl_label">
                Last name<span class="text-danger">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="text" name="applastname" id="applastname" class="form-control fl_input" data-ng-model="lastname" ng-required />
              <span class="form-bar"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback" show-errors="{ showSuccess: true }">
            <div class="fl_wrap">
              <label for="appemail" class="fieldLabel fl_label">
                Email<span class="text-danger">*</span>
              </label>
              <input type="email" name="appemail" id="appemail" class="form-control fl_input" data-ng-model="email" ng-required />
              <span class="form-bar"></span>
              <p ng-show="appForm.appemail.$invalid && !appForm.appemail.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter a valid email.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button id="btnSend" class="btn btn-red" ng-disabled="!firstname || !lastname || !email">Join us</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical as soon as I ask I solve

should have used get and just put the url ie:

It will then ass the query string using the input name as the query name so much simpler that what I was trying to do